# How can I use a template parameter for function types?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a `distance(x,y,f)` function that computes the number of times you have to apply `f` to `x` to get `y`.

For example, if `f = square` then `distance(2, 256, square) == 3`

The C++ code I have here is adapted from Elements of Programming by Stepanov & McJones:

```
DistanceType(F) distance(Domain(F) x, Domain(F) y, Square<int> f) {
    typedef DistanceType(F) N;
    // Precondition: y is reachable from x under f
    N n(0);
    while(x != y) {
        x = f(x);
        n += 1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Where `Domain(F)` and `DistanceType(F)` is `#define`d to be `int`

I decided to use functors for the function type, and made this `Square<T>` function template hierarchy:

```
template<typename T>
class Transformation {
    public:
        Transformation() {};
        virtual T operator() (T x) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Square : public Transformation<T> {
    public:
        virtual T operator() (T x) { return x * x; }
};
```

When I try the `distance` function out, it works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 256;
    Square<int> f = Square<int>();
    int d = distance(x, y, f);
    cout << "the distance between " << x << " and " 
        << y << " is " << d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Full gist here (compiles with g++)](https://gist.github.com/tlehman/ca6d1e96383be013474e43af16f98493)

## My question:

How can I make the type of `f` a template parameter?

I've tried this:

```
template<typename F>
DistanceType(F) distance(Domain(F) x, Domain(F) y, F f) {
    typedef DistanceType(F) N;
    // Precondition: y is reachable from x under f
    N n(0);
    while(x != y) {
        x = f(x);
        n += 1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

And changed the call to this:

```
typedef Square<int> F;
int d = distance<F>(x, y, f);
```

However, when I compile, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                from transformations.cpp:35:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::iterator_traits<Square<int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _InputIterator> typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = Square<int>]’
transformations.cpp:42:32:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:168:53: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘class Square<int>’
    typedef typename _Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:169:53: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class Square<int>’
    typedef typename _Iterator::value_type        value_type;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:170:53: error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘class Square<int>’
    typedef typename _Iterator::difference_type   difference_type;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:171:53: error: no type named ‘pointer’ in ‘class Square<int>’
    typedef typename _Iterator::pointer           pointer;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:172:53: error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘class Square<int>’
    typedef typename _Iterator::reference         reference;
```

And I don't understand the error. Why can't I use `Square<int>` as a template parameter?

Comment: Please show your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question body. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have two template parameters?

```
template <typename T, typename F>
unsigned long distance(T x, T y, F f)
{
    unsigned long n = 0;
    while(x != y)
    {
        x = f(x);
        ++n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This works with function pointers as well...

A variant *only* accepting functions:

```
template <typename T>
unsigned long distance(T x, T y, T (f)(T));
```

Comment: That variant only accepting functions, `T (f)(T)` is only going to work for a function pointer correct?

Comment: Okay, I think functors will be a better choice for this book, since the `Arity(F)` macros can be more easily defined in terms of methods on functors. I like the elegance of your approach though, thanks for answering!

Comment: That's up to you... First variant works with both, so you'll be fine. You can can use mismatching types with as well, as long as these are implicitly convertible one into the other; e. g. having T as `int`, but passing `std::exp` operating on doubles (OK, that one is overloaded, but that's another matter...). If that's now an advantage or rather disadvantage - well, I won't judge.